# Are the zeroes of the finite characteristic zeta functions dense in $\left\{s\in\mathbb{C}\mid\mathfrak{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{2}\right\}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, zeta-functions, weil-conjectures

If $p$ is a prime, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a natural number and $C$ is a nonsingular curve over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$, the $\zeta$ function associated to $C\mid_{\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}}$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
    \zeta_{\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}},C}(s)=\prod_{\mathfrak{m}\in\operatorname{Spec}(K)\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{1-N_{\mathfrak{m}}^{-s}}\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where $N_{\mathfrak{m}}=\#(\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{m})$ and $K$ is the function field of $C$.

Deligne has proven that the zeroes of $\zeta_{\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}},C}$ lie on the line $\mathfrak{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{2}$.

**Question**: Does the set
\begin{equation*}
    \left\{s\in\mathbb{C}\mid\exists \text{ prime } p, n\in\mathbb{N}, C\text{ curve over }\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}:\zeta_{\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}},C}(s)=0\right\}
\end{equation*}
lie dense in the line $\left\{s\in\mathbb{C}:\mathfrak{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{2}\right\}$?

Comment: Yes, though this is fairly trivial - zeta functions over $\mathbb F_q$ are $2\pi i/\log q$-periodic, so it is enough to pick for arbitrarily large $q$ some curves which have *some* zero - any curve of positive genus will work for that.

Comment: For *curves* the Riemann hypothesis was proved by Weil 25 years before Deligne treated higher-dimensional varieties. And you have omitted conditions on the curve for RH to hold: it should be projective, not affine, or missing points will lead to extra zeros off the critical line.

Comment: Also, the product should be not over $Spec(K)$, but over closed points on $C$ - if $C$ is affine, then this coincides with $Spec(R)\setminus\{0\}$, where $R$ is the *coordinate ring* of $C$, not its function field.